# Why does a nested if-statement work, but the "&&" operator doesn't? (letter counting script)

Tags: c#, if-statement, logical-operators

I need to write a script that counts how many times each letter occurs in a given text. I was successful at making it work, and although I'm sure that there's a better way to do it, the script does what it's supposed to do:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string text;
        Dictionary<char, int> letterCount = new Dictionary<char, int>();
        List<char> nonLetters = new List<char>
        {
            '.', '!', ',', '?', ':', ';', '#', '@', '$', '&', '(',')', '-',
            '+', '=', '\"','\'', ' ', '\n', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6',
            '7', '8','9', '0'
        };
        Console.WriteLine("Enter your text");
        text = Console.ReadLine();
        text = text.ToLower();
        for(int i = 0; i < text.Length; i++)
        {
            if (!letterCount.ContainsKey(text[i]))
            {
                if (!nonLetters.Contains(text[i]))
                {
                    letterCount.Add(text[i], 1);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                letterCount[text[i]] += 1;
            }
        }


        foreach (KeyValuePair<char, int> kvp in letterCount)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"{kvp.Key}: {kvp.Value}");
        }
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
```

My first attempt wasn't successful, though. And I don't understand why and what the difference is. This is what the for-loop in my initial code looked like:

```
for(int i = 0; i < text.Length; i++)
        {
            if (!letterCount.ContainsKey(text[i]) && !nonLetters.Contains(text[i]))
            {
                letterCount.Add(text[i], 1);
            }
            else
            {
                letterCount[text[i]] += 1;
            }
        }
```

This is what the Exception message says:
[System.Collections.Generic.KeyNotFoundException](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0MTHd.png)
["The given key'(' was not present in the dictionary](https://i.stack.imgur.com/liuIM.png)

Please, help me understand why using the "&&" operator doesn't work while the embedded if-statement with the same condition does.

Comment: It's simple. Lets make your `&&` expression in your secon example abstract by saying `A && B`. So, the expression is true if only A **AND** B are true. Which is different from  saying that only A is true (as in your 1st code example). So, now in your code A stands for "is the key not yet in the dictionary". If it does not then A is true, but in your code example `A && B` being true requires B being true as well. If it isn't, despite A being true (there no key being in the dictionary), the `if` statement hops over to the `else` branch, where you are trying to access the dictionary...

Comment: @MySkullCaveIsADarkPlace That could, and should, have been an answer

Comment: using `System.Linq`,`letterCount = text.Where(c => !nonLetters.Contains(c)).GroupBy(c => c).ToDictionary(g => g.Key, g.Count());`

Comment: @MySkullCaveIsADarkPlace Thank you so much, I understand the difference now!

Answer (score 4):

```cs
if (A)
{
    if (B)
    {
        X();
    }
}
else
{
    Y();
}
```

With this code, `Y` is executed if and only if `A` is `false`, regardless of the value of `B`.

```cs
if (A && B)
{
    X();
}
else
{
    Y();
}
```

With this code, `Y` is executed if `A` is `true` but `B` is `false`. The addition of the `else` blocks means that the logic is not the same in each case. Remove the `else` blocks and what's left will be functionally equivalent in both cases.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with your original code is not to do with the syntax but the logic; it does not handle the case where the character being read is a non-letter well.

In the scenario that the character being read is a non-letter, the if statement will be false. In this instance the code will attempt to increment the count for that non-letter character but it will not exist in the dictionary because the code does not add non-letter to the dictionary.